# React form hook ERROR : Why get error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I am trying to use react form hook. But it throws error.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm()

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data)

  console.log(watch("example")) // watch input value by passing the name of it

  return (
    /* "handleSubmit" will validate your inputs before invoking "onSubmit" */
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {/* register your input into the hook by invoking the "register" function */}
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />

      {/* include validation with required or other standard HTML validation rules */}
      <input {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })} />
      {/* errors will return when field validation fails  */}
      {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);
```

**JSON**

```
"name": "my-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.24.1",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
```

I tried to use a react form hook to use simple form. But it throws below error
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Comment: Did you import react react-dom?

Comment: Yes. I have imported react-dom